# SQL: Selecting data from table that doesn't exists in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In one table I have the following data:

[image]

As result of the query I want to have all the contracts (CONH%) that doesn't have a Support Contract.
In this case it should return 'CONHMIG0002'.

I tried the following query but it returns zero results:

```
SELECT Projectnr
FROM PRProject
WHERE Projectnr LIKE 'CONH%' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Parentproject
    FROM PRProject
    WHERE Projectnr LIKE 'CONS%')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `NOT IN` instead of `EXIST`.This way, you can easily filter out the values which are unique only to outer query

Try this :

```
SELECT Projectnr
FROM PRProject
WHERE Projectnr LIKE 'CONH%' AND Projectnr NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Projectnr --Parentproject
    FROM PRProject
    WHERE Projectnr LIKE 'CONS%')
```

Comment: That worked!! When do I have to use NOT EXISTS ? So I can understand it :)

Comment: `NOT EXIST` is only used to check if the query *returns* any data or not, so use it only to find if there is data for some condition or not....for *intersection* always prefer `NOT IN` instead of `exist` :)